# Datawarehouse: Multivalued Slowly Changing Dimensions

Tags: data-warehouse, scd

I am currently creating a datwarehouse for a (coffee) aggregator in latin america. They have two main business operations:

1. buying coffee from farmers and selling it in the international
   market and
2. providing micro-credit loans to these farmers to
   increase their yield.

My plan is to create a datawarehouse on top of their operational systems/dbs.

The first business process I will integrate is the credit operation, after that I will add the buying of the coffee of individual farmers.

For the credit operation I envision a single fact table which consists of the loan-amount, with dimensions to farmer, loan-officer etc. But before getting into the fact table concerning loans, I am currently working on the creation of the farmer dimension.

I have a nice little farmer dimension with some keys, geograhical location, sex, education, etc etc

I also would like to include the "economic production" of the farmer. This is information that is captured in the loan application process and basically says what kind of coffee they produce and the size of the land they produce this on. The relation between farmer and economic production is thus 1:n

Furthermore, this changes from year to year and is obviously only known for farmers that have done a loan application.

The goal of this information, is to be able to (even before the credit fact table is created) create some basic figures / insights on the farmers, their spatial distribution and their economic activity/output.

Iam thus thinking of having a farmer dimension connected to a "production dimension". This production dimension would be (1) time varying and (2) multivalued. The time variance I plan to implement according to type 2 (valid_from, valid_to and currently_valid columns).

Since I am rather new to the whole datawarehouse scene I have been reading a lot up on common techniques and principles, mainly from Kimball's excellent (!) book. However, I havent come across anything which describes such a dimension-dimension connection.

My questions therefore are:

1. is this common and considered a good approach?
2. where can I find some information on best practices concerning this matter

EDIT: A second possibility that I am thinking about would be to create some kind of a factless fact table which deals with "customer interaction" (e.g. the loan application process in which such information from farmers is collected). This fact table would then have a FK to the farmer and FK to the production dimension as well as a FK to a time dimension table. As it has no facts associated with it, this would only form some kind of a 1:n linking table. The only difference with the former method would be that the time-dimension is now in a seperate table as opposed to be included in the production table in my opinion..

EDIT2: Or should I create perhaps a production fact table, although it does not coincide with a business process of the aggregator. In that case probably the surface area to produce a certain crop would become the measure, and potentially the crop types / varieties etc would go into a seperate dimension.

Comment: Quick thoughts- sounds like a factless fact to me. Is it always by year that it varies? In which case your time dimension is year- but you could have start and end dates if not. And if other measures could apply, feel free to put them in the fact. There's a fine line between considering your table a dimension to dimension bridge, and a factless fact.

Comment: Hi Rich, thanks for your reply. I'm currently thinking in the same direction, e.g. modeling as a fact. This morning I had a new idea, to actually use the "size of the land used by the farmer to grow the certain product" as the measure in the "production fact". Besides the "production fact" I then create a "production dimension" with the metadata of the measure (which type of coffee etc etc). Although this means that I no longer can use "size of land" in any filter operations.. since it's a fact and not a dimension.. maybe I have to put it both in the fact and the dimension..?